# how to monitor a linux system on amazon ec2 without cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, monitoring

I would like to monitor the following on Amazon ec2 instances loaded with amazon linux, every X minutes :

disk statistics
process stats (similar to what `top` does)
ram usage
check if my scripts are running fine

should I use my own scripts and things or are there any tools that already achieve this ?
I searched and there was a suggestion about [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

what seems to be the better approach ?

Comment: belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: is there a way I can move this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great article on scale. About halfway down, the author lists monitoring tools and how they differ.

http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/8/16/scaling-an-aws-infrastructure-tools-and-patterns.html

We've implemented Cacti, it was very easy, it creates all sorts of graphs/reports (most of what you mentioned). Munin is one that he lists as well, but we have not tried that solution yet.

Comment: I vote against Cacti. It is a huge PITA to add hosts to it. This is really annoying when you're running on EC2 and hosts come and go often.

Comment: @Spike Gronim : You could also suggest some tool which is not PITA ... :)

Comment: Well my team is using Splunk which is not free, hence no mention. We also rolled some of our own.